# 1 Equation 4 Unknowns values

Tags: calculus

I have to establish a budget and target for 4 months, up to August we have the Year to Date which is the total sales we had until August included.

For a POS (They all have different ratio that is why I am struggling) we have :

Year Target 200,000 and Year to Date 51,729.

September target is 13,300
October target is 15,000
November target is 24,000
December target is 72,300

Year to Go = 148,271

These are the first targets without in count the Year to date, now we need to adjust them - we could do it manually but I would like it to be very precise hense this is why I am looking to find a formula.

Initially I do not have the coefficient as they have been set without formula therefore I need to find the initial ratio within the formula (I work on Excel)

So far I have :

1 - (year target - monthly target) * (year target - Year to date)

in order to find the amount of September we should target to reach 200,000 following the same coefficient that September had with 200,000 but I need to modify this ratio and I do not know how.

1 - ( 200,000 - 13,300 ) * 148,721

Am I clear enough? Could you guide me or give me a hint ?

I ended up with this to try to clear things up :

200,000 = 51,729 + 148,721x + 148,721y + 148,721z + 148,721w

And need to solve x, y, z and w, to find the new target for the last 4 months.

I am a bit confuse if, first of all, it is possible to solve this with just these informations ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about some analytical solution to your question, but, can't you just distribute any target not hit, in say September, over the remaining months, in the same ratios for the remaining months? Or using whatever ratios/idea of demand you used to set your targets in the first place.

Thus you can update your targets for the remaining months quickly and easily, and not worry about deriving some formula for your problem?

Comment: The thing is if I distribute the same ratio for the leftover I will have still some leftover as it wouldn't reach 1. For example for September it's worth 0.0665 of the global target, but it was a target over 12 months and now we need to adjust this to get it over 4. Maybe I should find a way to increase this ratio but I do not know how ?